# Must declare the scalar variable "@userid"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am getting:

> Must declare the scalar variable "@userid".

On

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Items["AlbumID"] != null)
{
    Page.DataBind();
    ddlAlbum.Items.FindByValue(HttpContext.Current.Items["AlbumID"].ToString()).Selected = true;
}
```

I believe it has something to do with:

```
 <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SLIITComDBConnectionString %>" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [AlbumId], [AlbumName] FROM [Album]  WHERE (userid=@userid) ">
                   <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter DefaultValue="1" Name="AlbumID" 
                    QueryStringField="AlbumID" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: Why do you think a SQL statement would complain about `@userid` when there is no `@userid` in the statement? Clearly, it is complaining about something that _does_ have `@userid` in it.

Comment: i have edited the question, i pasted wrong code.

Comment: Clearly, your parameter needs to be `userId` if you refer to `@userid` in the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SQL query you use @userid var, which is not declared!

```
SELECT [AlbumId], [AlbumName] FROM [Album]  WHERE (userid=@userid)
```

There is great info about your problem
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In general, this error means that the statement or stored procedure you are calling requires a parameter named `@userid`, and that you have not supplied it. Maybe you spelled the parameter incorrectly, or maybe you thought there were two parameters and only supplied one parameter. But the underlying meaning is very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Your query clearly needs  a `@userid`

```
SELECT [AlbumId], [AlbumName] FROM [Album]  WHERE (userid=@userid)
```

You have not supplied this in your `<SelectParameters>`
Set that and you should be good to go.